# MYSQL Inner Joins with OR condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables with the following columns:

Table1:

```
userId | seriesId | content
```

Table2:

```
followerId | followeeId
```

Table3:

```
followerId | seriesId
```

What I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
SELECT Table1.content 
FROM Table1 
    (INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.followeeId=Table1.userId WHERE Table2.followerId=X) 
OR (INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table3.seriesId=Table1.seriesId WHERE Table3.followerId=X)
```

'X' will be some dynamically generated number. I'm not sure if this is even the right approach but you get what I'm trying to do right? My question is, what is the right way to implement something like this? Please let me know in the comments if any part of my question is not clear.

Comment: What result do you expect? It's not entirely clear from your "pseudo-query"

Comment: I need to select 'content' from Table1 where either one of the two Inner Joins is satisfied, but not necessarily both

Comment: Why you are joining these two table when you are not using their columns? Please make your case a bit more clear

Comment: When I'm not using their columns? Sorry but did you even read my question carefully?

Comment: Ok, Now I understand what you are trying to do. you generate a random number then first you check either any user is associated with this id or not if yes then get the its record from the table. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, either a user or a series, but not necessarily both. Anyway I got it now. The Accepted answer is what I needed. :)

Comment: I am not spending my time here to answer, actually I am trying to learn :) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `UNION`:

```
SELECT Table1.content
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.followeeId=Table1.userId 
WHERE Table2.followerId=X
UNION
SELECT Table1.content
INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table3.seriesId=Table1.seriesId 
WHERE Table3.followerId=X
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this too..

```
SELECT Table1.content 
FROM Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table2.followeeId=Table1.userId 
LEFT JOIN Table3 ON Table3.seriesId=Table1.seriesId
where Table2.followerId=X or Table3.followerId=X;
```

The other way is Union

```
select table1.content
from table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.followeeId=Table1.userId 
where followerId = X
union
select table1.content
from table1
INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table3.seriesId = Table1.seriesId
where Table3.followerId = X;
```

Comment: Looks good now.  I actually tend to use the first one more often since it allows things to get more complicated if needed.  Internally MySQL will often convert it to a union anyway.